# PandasのDataFrame.applyメソッドで、データがゼロ件のときの処理方法について

Tags: python, python3, pandas

DataFrame.applyメソッドの戻り値の型が、
データがＮ件のときはSeries型が戻り、
データがＮ件のときはDataFrame型が戻るため困っています。

デバッグしたところ、データがゼロ件のときも、applyする関数が呼び出され、
例外が発生したことが原因でした。
ゼロ件のときは、どのような処理にするべきか、教えていただけないでしょうか。
（どのように修正するのが正しいでしょうか？）

ゼロ件のときを考慮して、applyを適用する関数に、判定文を入れなければならないものなのでしょうか？
もしくは、ゼロ件のときは、applyを適用する関数が呼び出されないよう指定できないでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd

print('PandasのVersion', pd.__version__)


def concat_col(series: pd.Series):
    """ふたつの列の値を連結する。"""
    print(type(series))
    print(series)
    return series['aa'] + '_' + series['bb']  # ←dfがゼロ件のとき、ここで例外が発生します。

# ◇Ｎ件の場合
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'aa': 'aa0', 'bb': 'bb0'},
    {'aa': 'aa1', 'bb': 'bb1'},
], index=[0, 1])
display(df)
series = df.apply(concat_col, axis='columns')
print('戻り値の型:', type(series))

# ◇ゼロ件の場合
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[], columns=['XX', 'YY'])
display(df)
series = df.apply(concat_col, axis='columns')
print('戻り値の型:', type(series))
```

以下、実行結果です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `if len(df): series = df.apply(concat_col, axis='columns')` みたいに行えばよいのでは？ ゼロの場合に 0件の `series`が必要なら elseで対処するとか。例外が発生するのは `concat_col` 関数内で `series['aa']` など, 存在しないからカラム名指定してるからでは？

Comment: `apply` に `result_type='reduce'` を付けるとよいかと思います。`axis='columns'` の場合には適用する関数は呼び出されません。(Pandas の内部で専用の処理メソッド(`pandas.FrameApply.apply_empty_result`)が実行されます)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントでのアドバイスを参考に、以下のように`result_type='reduce'`を指定することでゼロ件の場合はapplyを適用する関数は呼び出されなくなりました。
さらに、applyの結果はゼロ件のSeriesを戻すようになり、期待した結果が得られました。

```
series = df.apply(concat_col, axis='columns', result_type='reduce')
```